# Exception thrown when using Java Generic SOAPClient (SAAJ)?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, saaj

I’m trying to use the following SOAPClient for Java (details which I’ve obtained from the following tutorial http://users.skynet.be/pascalbotte/rcx-ws-doc/saajpost.htm).

However, it seems to be throwing an exception.

Here is my code:

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage msg;
MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
msg = mf.createMessage();
SOAPPart part = msg.getSOAPPart();
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new File("samples/input1.xml”));
part.setContent(source);
msg.saveChanges();

String endpoint = "http://ws1.parasoft.com/glue/calculator";

SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection conn = scf.createConnection();
javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage response = conn.call(msg, endpoint);
TransformerFactory tff = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer tf = tff.newTransformer();
Source sc = response.getSOAPPart().getContent();
ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(ostream);
tf.transform(sc, result);
conn.close();

System.out.println(new String(ostream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8”));
```

In this example, we assume `samples/input1.xml` holds the following:

```
<s11:Envelope xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s11:Body>
      <ns1:add xmlns:ns1="http://www.parasoft.com/wsdl/calculator/">
         <ns1:x>248</ns1:x>
         <ns1:y>365</ns1:y>
      </ns1:add>
   </s11:Body>
</s11:Envelope>
```

The sample web-service that I’m trying to use can be found here:
http://www.service-repository.com/client/operations

When running the above Java-code (using the SOAPClient library), the following exception is thrown:

```
Jul 19, 2012 3:50:11 AM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post
SEVERE: SAAJ0008: Bad Response; cannot find /calculator
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (404cannot find /calculator
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:148)
    at corebus.test.deprecated.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:1870)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (404cannot find /calculator
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    ... 1 more

CAUSE:

com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (404cannot find /calculator
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
```

Using this web-site, it seems the services is up and running, and working well.

I have even verified the service-endpoint is active, by conducted a simple cURL request, which surprisingly produces the correct output.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction:http://www.parasoft.com/wsdl/calculator/" -d@soap-request.xml http://ws1.parasoft.com/glue/calculator
```

The output produced is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/‘>
    <soap:Body>
        <n:addResponse xmlns:n='http://www.parasoft.com/wsdl/calculator/‘>
            <n:Result xsi:type='xsd:float'>613.0</n:Result>
        </n:addResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So, my question is: Firstly, what is wrong with the Java-code? And how could it be fixed? Or also, is there any other better/more-reliable Generic SOAPClient Library that would be recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the WSDL by attaching ?wsdl in your url in browser or somehow get he WSDL. Check if the WSDl specifies if it is a document style or PRC style and based on that prepare the input xml.

If possible use SOAP UI tool which can be very handy.

Comment: I’ve been looking into soapUI.. however, if I’m not mistaken, the dependencies needed to integrate with Java seems enormous. Do you (or anyone) have experience using soapUI as a Java Lib?